# How to use array_search or in_array function on a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
static $cnt=0;
$name='victor';
$coll = array(
    'dep1'=>array(
        'fy'=>array('john','johnny','victor'),
        'sy'=>array('david','arthur'),
        'ty'=>array('sam','joe','victor')
    ),
        'dep2'=>array(
        'fy'=>array('natalie','linda','molly'),
        'sy'=>array('katie','helen','sam','ravi','vipul'),
        'ty'=>array('sharon','julia','maddy')
    )
    );

    function array_find($name,$arr)
    {
        global $cnt;
    if(!(is_array($arr)))
        return false;

    foreach($arr as $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        array_find($name,$val);
        else
        {
        $val=strtolower($val);
        $item=strtolower($name);
        if($val==$name)
            $cnt+=1;
        }
    }
    }

    array_find($name,$coll);

    if($cnt==0)
    echo "$name was Not Found";
    else
    echo "$name was found $cnt times.";
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: want to search a name and count the repetitions.

Comment: `victor was found 2 times.` isn't that right ?

Comment: and 1st of all, how the hell to edit that code. i've wasted an hour or so and still couldn't get with it !!

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yup !!

Comment: I edited the code so you that was your problem ;) It works as expected. You can delete the question by the way

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` would be useful

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran not at all bro. just wanna know how array_search() or in_array() could be used instead of recursion ?

Comment: @Girish may i know how ?

Comment: @Always_Cool, `in_array` or `array_search` will not work on nested arrays. You need to use recursion whatsoever !

Comment: @Girish sry but i think u didn't got me right. i need to find the sub array name in which the name(s) was found. like victor was found in "dep1,dep2" sorry again if this que is pretty stupid to be asked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, hope it will work

```
<?php
static $cnt = 0;
$name = 'victor';
$coll = array(
    'dep1' => array(
        'fy' => array('john', 'johnny', 'victor'),
        'sy' => array('david', 'arthur'),
        'ty' => array('sam', 'joe', 'victor')
    ),
    'dep2' => array(
        'fy' => array('natalie', 'linda', 'molly'),
        'sy' => array('katie', 'helen', 'sam', 'ravi', 'vipul'),
        'ty' => array('sharon', 'julia', 'maddy')
    )
);

function recursive_search(&$v, $k, $search_query){
    global $cnt;
    if($v == $search_query){
        ++$cnt;
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($coll, 'recursive_search' , $name);
if ($cnt == 0)
    echo "$name was Not Found";
else
    echo "$name was found $cnt times.";
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/115159)

Comment: yes, that is very helpful. Now how could i get the intermediate array name i.e. whether the name was found in "dep1" or "dep2" ?

Comment: sry but i think u didn't got me right. i need to find the sub array name in which the name(s) was found. like victor was found in "dep1,dep2" sorry again if this que is pretty stupid to be asked :(